# Accessing information from nested struct passed to function

Tags: c, struct, nested

I have the following code:

```
struct wordPair {
       char* englishWord;
       char* foreignWord;
};

struct dictionary {
       struct wordPair ** data;
       int nbwords;
       int size;
};
```

Say I have `struct dictionary *dictionaryPtr` filled with some data, and I pass it to the following function:

```
char* dictionary_translate( struct dictionary* d,
                        const char* const english_word,
                        const char* const foreign_word)
```

Within the function `dictionary_translate`, how can I access the data from the `struct wordPair` that is nested within the passed struct? I need the function to return a strdup of either `englishWord` or `foreignWord`.

I was trying `d->data->englishWord`, but this gives me the error "request for member 'englishWord' in something not a structure or union".

UPDATE!

What I need the function `dictionary_translate` to do is determine if there is a matching word pair that contains one of the words passed to it, and return the `strdup` of the translation (the other word in the pair). Here is the array of words I have defined:

```
const char* test_translations[NB_TESTS][NB_COLS] =
{
    {"hello", "hola"},
    {"cat", "gato"},
    {"dog", "perro"},
    {"thanks", "gracias"},
    {"pants", "pantalones"},
    {"shoes", "zapatos"},
};
```

This is how I'm calling the function in the first test I'm trying, which is when the translate function is passed an English word and is required to return a foreign word:

```
char* translationPtr = NULL;

for (i = 0; i < NB_TESTS; i++) {
    translationPtr = dictionary_translate(dictionaryPtr, test_translations[i][0], NULL);
    printf("English Word %s translated: %s\n", test_translations[i][0], translationPtr);
}
```

Here is the translate function as I have it so far...

```
char* dictionary_translate( struct dictionary* d,
                            const char* const english_word,
                            const char* const foreign_word){
    int i;

    if (d == NULL) return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < d->nbwords; i++) {
        if (strcmp(english_word, d->data[i]->englishWord) == 0)
            return strdup(d->data[i]->foreignWord);
        else if (strcmp(foreign_word, d->data[i]->foreignWord) == 0)
            return strdup(d->data[i]->englishWord);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

As soon as the program gets to the translation function, it crashes. I can't make sense of the debugger to find out what is going on, but it seems like `translationPtr` never has a value other than NULL (0x0). I'm new with the debugger, so I'm sure it could tell me more if I knew how to read it.

Comment: maybe you need to dereference data, as in d->(*data)->englishWord, because it looks like data is a pointer to an array.

Comment: @DoctorZero: that is not syntactically valid C.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't entirely clear what your function is to do, but about the simplest implementation that might legitimately work is:

```
#include <string.h>

struct wordPair
{
    char *englishWord;
    char *foreignWord;
};

struct dictionary
{
    struct wordPair **data;
    int nbwords;
    int size;
};

extern char *dictionary_translate(struct dictionary *d,
                                  const char *const english_word,
                                  const char *const foreign_word);

char *dictionary_translate(struct dictionary *d,
                           const char *const english_word,
                           const char *const foreign_word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d->nbwords; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(english_word, d->data[i]->englishWord) == 0)
            return strdup(d->data[i]->foreignWord);
        else if (strcmp(foreign_word, d->data[i]->foreignWord) == 0)
            return strdup(d->data[i]->englishWord);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think you should review the design of your `struct dictionary`.  Using a double pointer seems unnecessary (or the reason for using it is not obvious).  The only advantage is that you'd have a contiguous array of pointers to `struct wordPair`, while the actual `struct wordPair` elements need not be contiguously allocated themselves.  The following code is a more orthodox definition, assuming that a contiguous array of `struct wordPair` is not a problem:

```
#include <string.h>

struct wordPair
{
    char *englishWord;
    char *foreignWord;
};

struct dictionary
{
    struct wordPair *data;
    int nbwords;
    int size;
};

extern char *dictionary_translate(struct dictionary *d,
                                  const char *const english_word,
                                  const char *const foreign_word);

char *dictionary_translate(struct dictionary *d,
                           const char *const english_word,
                           const char *const foreign_word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d->nbwords; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(english_word, d->data[i].englishWord) == 0)
            return strdup(d->data[i].foreignWord);
        else if (strcmp(foreign_word, d->data[i].foreignWord) == 0)
            return strdup(d->data[i].englishWord);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Given the sample test code where one of the arguments to `dictionary_translate()` is a NULL pointer, the code in the function must be revised not to dereference the argument if it is null. This assumes the double-pointer version of `struct dictionary`.

```
char *dictionary_translate(struct dictionary *d,
                           const char *const english_word,
                           const char *const foreign_word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d->nbwords; i++)
    {
        if (englishWord != NULL && strcmp(english_word, d->data[i]->englishWord) == 0)
            return strdup(d->data[i]->foreignWord);
        else if (foreignWord != NULL && strcmp(foreign_word, d->data[i]->foreignWord) == 0)
            return strdup(d->data[i]->englishWord);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you input! I updated my original question. I implemented your proposed function (with a couple of additions required by the instructor), and some more information. The problem is now crashing when run, but your means of accessing the information within the nested struct seemed to work great!

Answer (score -3):

```
d->(*data)->englishWord
```

Should compile.

Comment: I think you should go consult a compiler for its views on the compilability of your expression.  My view (and I admit to not being a C compiler) is that it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: I was trying to be polite.  You need to run the code past a C compiler — it does not compile.  If you have a C compiler where it does compile, please provide the full details.  Adding the line `if (strcmp(d->(*data)->englishWord, "aleph") == 0) return NULL;` to the code I showed leads to GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks saying: `dict.c: In function ‘dictionary_translate’:` and
`dict.c:24:19: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token`
at `if (strcmp(d->(*data)->englishWord, "aleph") == 0)`
and the caret `^` marks the `(` of `(*data)`.

Comment: A syntax that would work is `(*d->data)->englishWord`.  It is equivalent to `d->data[0]->englishWord`.